# How can I life this 4/5 up to the same height as rest of the line

Tags: css

I am trying to make a row of text in a table cell level but am getting nowhere

The HTML is

```
 <`td class="statscenter"><span class="float1851l">I <span class="herboyninetynine">4<span class="strike"><span class="underline">5</span></span></span></span> <span class="float1851r">B &#95;</span> U &#95;</td>`
```

The result is that where the 4 is placed over the crossed out 5 the underline is pushed down. I know why. It's because of the acions of the class "herboyninetynine"

```
.herboyninetynine {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; /* Enables to rows to fit on one line */
    font-size:.875em;
    line-height:.875;
    margin:0;
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to resolve it. I have tried margin-top/bottom, padding-top/bottom. I have tried putting it in a div but I get nowehere.

I can't seem to add an image but it shows like this with the 4 slightly above the B and the 5 crossed out and slightly below it

I 4 B _ U _
  5

Comment: Can you try to explain the issue a little more? I truly don't understand it and the code doesn't seems to work correctly too.

Comment: May be you can provide a fiddle?

Comment: The 4 sticks out above the letter B and the 5 goes below it. I am trying to create the effect that someone has written a 5 on a line, then crossed it out and written a 4 above it. The code does work. It's on the web page now, but I don't think I can post urls can I

Comment: How do I provide a fiddle?

Comment: OK. The link is: http://www.c5d.co.uk/1851.php  and it is after the entry numbered 29 Edward Slade about three quarters of the way down

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.herboyninetynine {
  display: inline-block;
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
  font-size: .875em;
  line-height: .875;
  margin: 0;
}
.float1851l {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Well it has partially worked, but what you have given has had the effect of moving the letter I up as well. However I shall be able to solve it from there Thanks you very much. I did try and mark your answer positively but the system doesn't allow me to

Comment: @AlbertMaytonn - Where do you want the `I`? Try to remove the comment (`/*` and `*/`) around the `vertical-align: middle;` and then mess with the value in `top: -7px;`.

Comment: I want the I level with the U and the B. I thought I might jut put them in two separate floats one with what what I had already and one which you provided for the 4/5

Comment: Exactly like that

Comment: @AlbertMaytonn - That's how it shows to me when I change the page with my code posted here. (on class `herboyninetynine`: comment vertical align; on class `float1851l`: add position relative and top -7px)

Comment: OK, I'll have to adjust the herboy etc..... I use it many time throughout the site so will need a new class. I'll confirm shortly

Comment: @AlbertMaytonn - You may also just add that CSS style to the element directly using the HTML attribute `<span class="float1851l" style="position:relative;top:-7px">` and `<span class="herboyninetynine" style="vertical-align:initial">`. Or just add `id`s to the elements and style to them with the CSS selector `#IdName{/* style */}`.

Comment: I couldn't it work with what you had given exactly, but by using you code solely around the 4/5 it worked absolutely fine.  Thanks you very much. CSS is relatively new to me, but I thought in line styling was poor form.

This is what I eventually used with your code being the class "..upabit"<td class="statscenter"><span class="float1851l">I</span> <span class="float1851lupabit"><span class="herboyninetynine">4<span class="strike"><span class="underline">5</span></span></span></span></span> <span class="float1851r">B &#95;</span> U &#95;</td>

Comment: @AlbertMaytonn - Glad to help! If you please don't mind, could you accept my answer so it helps me out a little bit? :)

Comment: Well it has partially worked, but what you have given has had the effect of moving the letter I up as well. However I shall be able to solve it from there Thanks you very much. I did try and mark your answer positively but the system doesn't allow me to – Albert Maytonn 3 hours ago   (It won't let me do it because I am a new member to S/o